# Issue with taking screenshots using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I want to take screenshots of webpages using Selenium WebDriver. While the basic functionality seems to work, there would be an issue with capturing a specific type of webpages like [pesco billing](https://pescobilling.pk/) and [fesco bill](https://fescobilling.pk/) sites. Here's the problem.

I am able to take screenshots of most webpages without any problems. However, there are some webpages with certain dynamic elements or overlays, the resulting screenshot would appears to be missing those elements. It's as if the screenshot would be taken before these dynamic elements are fully loaded.

Here's a simplified version of the Java code:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

public class WebpageScreenshot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try {
            driver.get("https://pescobilling.pk/");

            // Sleep for a few seconds to allow dynamic elements to load (not a good practice)
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            // Take the screenshot
            File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            // Save the screenshot
            // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is related to the timing of taking the screenshot, as some elements are loaded dynamically after the initial page load. In the code snippet above, I added a Thread.sleep to pause execution, but this is not an ideal solution, and it doesn't always work perfectly.

What is the recommended approach to ensure that the screenshot is taken after all dynamic elements have loaded? Is there a more reliable way to capture the entire webpage, including these dynamic elements?

Comment: Use WebDriverWaits with Explicit Conditions:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/